# SAS backwards retain

Tags: sas

I have a large data set that can be dissected into the following:

```
ID  x
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   1
1   1
```

I have one ID variable telling me which individual that the X value corresponds to.

The X variable is 0 if no event has occurred for this individual and 1 if an event has occurred.

I'm interested in creating a variable which tells me if an event has at all occurred for a customers during my whole time series for that specific ID, as seen in X2 below.

```
ID  x   x2
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
1   1   1
```

Hence x2 takes the value 1 across all observations because x takes the value 1 in at least one instance.

I have looked at creating a reversed lag through the "SAS leading technique" but it doesn't seem to be able to retain the value, so I would need to do a reverse lag multiple times which is not an option since my actual data set contains thousands of rows and every ID needs different amounts of lags.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried the answers from both Joe and floydn and they both worked great. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is the double DoW loop.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if x then x2=1;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

This loops through the dataset once to find the value of x2, sets it, and then loops through again to output the data.  You don't actually `retain` anything because it's all in one data step loop iteration for a single ID - `x2` isn't being reset except between IDs.

This is reasonably fast, as long as you don't have more records per ID than you can fit in the read buffer, as it will buffer the first read and thus not have to re-read from disk a second time.

Answer (score 2):

Try a SQL solution.

```
proc sql;
create table flagged as 
select
  a.*,
  b.x2
from
  table  a
  join
  (select 
    id,
    max(x) as x2
  from table
  group by id)  b
    on
    a.id = b.id
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by merging the data with itself, applying a `where=` dataset option to the second copy.  You will need to keep a copy of the X variable, but renamed, so that it can used in the `where=`.  You could use this renamed variable as the new `X2`, but then you would need to convert missings to zeros.  Or you could use the `IN=` dataset option to generate the new `X2` variable with 0/1 values.

```
data want;
  merge have have(in=in2 keep=id x rename=(x=x3) where=(x3=1)) ;
  by id;
  x2 = in2;
  drop x3;
run;
```